# How to handle Synonym files in elasticsearch Elastic Cloud

Tags: azure, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, synonym, elastic-cloud

We have the requirement that we have to maintain multiple synonym files as token filter for an index.

But how do I do that in Azure managed Elatic Cloud Service?

I saw in the documentation (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-synonym-tokenfilter.html) that it is generally posssible to add synonym file/s to an index.
But therefore you have to upload a file. This is not possilbe, or at least I don't know how to do so in Azure Managed Elastic Cloud Service.

Answer (score 0):

On Elastic Cloud, you can [create a bundle](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html#ec-prepare-custom-bundles) containing your synonym file and upload it as an extension.

You synonym file needs to be placed in a `/dictionaries` folder at the root of the ZIP bundle

```
/dictionaries
  +-- synonyms.txt
```

When zipped, you can go in your ES Cloud console to [Features > Create extension](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html#ec-add-your-plugin) and upload your ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for you comment. Can I also "update" my synonyms when my cluster/deployment is done? For example if i get a new file every day or week

Comment: If you open the link I gave you, you'll see a section called ["Update your extension"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud/current/ec-custom-bundles.html#ec-update-bundles-and-plugins)

Comment: And how do I add the extension/bundle to my existing index?

Comment: In your index settings you can reference the synonyms file uploaded to `/app/config/dictionaries` of your node

Comment: @ Val thank you so much already for all your time and answers. But how do I add it exactly to my existing index in elastic cloud?

Comment: @JoshHirsch After uploading the file to that directory, you can update your existing index mapping to use the synonyms_path in filters.